# can we programatically get all the live adapters in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am writing a spring integration app and so far I am able to control most of the adapters and config with the control bus and other similar features . The graph controller also provides visibility over the current state of the app and the integration graph which is good .

But I have a requirement to somehow programatically get all the live adapters in spring integration which I can show the the user and have the ability to stop/start them at will as per the below control bus .

```
   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("controlChannel").controlBus().get();
   }

//Gateway 

public interface AdapterController {

    @Gateway(requestChannel="controlChannel")
    void control(String command);
}
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext.
```

Then use `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractEndpoint.class)` to get all integration components; you can call `getComponentType()` and `getComponentName()` on each.

Comment: Ahh thanks was thinking should be the context. This is great now I can do stuff I did with camel 

Comment: Since that gives you a hard reference to each endpoint (map keyed by bean name/id), you don't really need to use the control bus; you can invoke stop/start directly on the endpoint.

Comment: Yup was doing via this only now